# How to order an asp-src-include statement?

Tags: asp.net-core

I used:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script asp-src-include="~/js/*.js"></script>
</environment>
```

I had two js files, `~/js/jquery.js` and `~/js/bootstrap.js` but the outputted script tags were in alphabetical order, i.e. `bootstrap.js` then `jquery.js`, but jQuery needs to be first.

I got around it by changing to:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Is there a way to still use `asp-src-include` but to have more control over the order it uses?

Comment: Other than prefixing the names with a number (i.e. in gulp task which copies them to the wwwroot folder)... I don't know. In theory you could generate your own tag helper that checks for a *.json file containing the configuration(s) and ordering and use that instead of `asp-src-include`. Check out the "Creating Your Own Tag Helpers" section in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx